# Color filenames according to $LS_COLORS in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a simple vim syntax file for random note takings for work.

I would like to color filenames according to `$LS_COLORS`. I can prefix a filename in the notes file with something random, like '·', to make it easier for vim to tell "oh boy, there's a filename coming up!". But how would I go about implementing the actual coloring accoring to the environment variable `$LS_COLORS`?

Comment: Note that there's a [whole stackexchange site dedicated to `vi` / `vim`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh. Didn't know. Thank you.